# Convert and move .zip and .xml

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I'm trying to make a program where I convert and move the files, but I'm not succeeding, the error always indicates the paths that I put, but I don't know how to solve it.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import os
import xmltodict, json

## Extract the ZIP files
zipCemig = ZipFile('Consulta_Saldo_GD.zip', 'r')
zipCemig.extract('C:/Users/andre.friedrich/Desktop/Bot CEMIG/XML Cemig')

## Convert XML files
xml = 'C:/Users/andre.friedrich/Desktop/Bot CEMIG/XML Cemig'
lista = os.listdir(xml)
lista_len = len(lista)
x = 0
while x < lista_len:
    with open(lista) as f:
        d = xmltodict.parse(f.read())
    with open("cemig"+x+".json", 'w') as f:
        json.dump(d, f)
    x += 1

## Move already converted files
oldAdress = 'C:/Users/andre.friedrich/Desktop/Bot CEMIG/XML Cemig'
newAdressXml = 'C:/Users/andre.friedrich/Desktop/Bot CEMIG/XML Arquivo Morto'
newAdressJson = 'C:/Users/andre.friedrich/Desktop/Bot CEMIG/JSON Cemig'
lista = os.listdir(oldAdress)
for arquivo in lista:
    if ".xml" in arquivo:
        os.rename(f"{oldAdress}/{arquivo}", f"{newAdressXml}/{arquivo}")
    if ".json" in arquivo:
        os.rename(f"{oldAdress}/{arquivo}", f"{newAdressJson}/{arquivo}")
```

I would like the program to convert and move the files to the indicated paths.

I'm also getting an error

```
TypeError: ZipFile.extract() missing 1 required positional argument: 'member'
```

Comment: You see an error. Why don't you add the error message here in your question?

Comment: \ in string is *ESCAPE STRING* .. none of your paths are correct because of that. Either use \\ or use *raw string* prefix by adding r in front of the quote character.

Comment: i invert \ to this /, but now i receiving this error, TypeError: ZipFile.extract() missing 1 required positional argument: 'member', and i don´t figure out to solve this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it could be the backslashes in the file paths.
In Python, backslashes are used to escape special characters, so they need to be escaped themselves by using another backslash.

- Try with forward `/` instead and see if that changes anything.
- Or double backslashes `\\`

Also in the last loop where you convert the XML to the .json I would rephrase it more to look like this

```
for arquivo in lista:
    if arquivo.endswith(".xml"):
        os.rename(os.path.join(oldAdress, arquivo), os.path.join(newAdressXml, arquivo))
    if arquivo.endswith(".json"):
        os.rename(os.path.join(oldAdress, arquivo), os.path.join(newAdressJson, arquivo))
```

Comment: i changed, but now i receiving this error, TypeError: ZipFile.extract() missing 1 required positional argument: 'member'

Comment: @Guspex either you specify which file from the zipobject you want to extract (that is what member is) or you use the extractall() method instead of extract(). I suggest to read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extract)

Comment: @CAPSLOCK believe me, I read it, I know that for some it may seem like something for a beginner who doesn't read it before asking, but yes, I'm a beginner, and unfortunately I read it and didn't understand.

Comment: @CAPSLOCK, I made some changes, however now I got this error. - TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Comment: @Guspex it is not easy without knowing what the changes are. I suggest to create a new question (where you show the updated script) to fix this issue. It seems that your original problem (the path) is now solved. EDIT: also show the error message you are now getting in the new question

Comment: @CAPSLOCK, OK, tks a lot....

Comment: @Malene Gravlund, tks to you too, you help a solve my first problem.

Comment: @Guspex thanks for the comment, sorry i could not help with the rest.